# Rsync over SSH path with spaces does not work with quotes

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am able to successfully RSYNC over SSH as long as the paths do not have spaces in them.

When the path does have spaces, it does not work. I have tried slashes, quotes, and double quotes.

When I use slashes, the output states that it is a success but I do not see any transferred files.

```
rsync -avz /path\ with\ spaces/ user@remotelocation:/media/another\ path\ with/spaces/
```

When I use single or double quotes, it tells me that permission is denied after entering my password

```
rsync -avz '/path with spaces/' 'user@remotelocation:/media/another path with/spaces/'
```

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Expanding on rzr's answer with example code and references, just add the `-s` flag, quote the paths, and don't worry about escaping spaces in the remote path:

```
rsync -avzs '/path with spaces/' 'user@remotelocation:/media/another path with/spaces/'
```

---

For reference, the options specified by the OP:

- -a, archive mode, equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)

  - Includes:
  - -r, --recursive, recurse into directories
  - -l, --links, copy symlinks as symlinks
  - -p, --perms, preserve permissions
  - -t, --times, preserve modification times
  - -g, --group, preserve group
  - -o, --owner, preserve owner (super-user only)
  - -devices, preserve device files (super-user only)
  - -specials, preserve special files
- -v, --verbose, increase verbosity
- -z, --compress, compress file data during the transfer

The additional parameter needed:

- -s, --protect-args, no space-splitting, wildcard chars only

Answer (score 15):

You need to escape spaces in both local shell and remote shell. Try this:

```
rsync -avz '/path with spaces/' 'user@remotelocation:/media/another\ path\ with/spaces/'
```

The source, `/path with spaces/` in the local shell can be escaped only via putting single quotes around it i.e. `'/path with spaces/'`.

On the other hand in case of the destination, the local shell is escaped by putting single quotes and the spaces are escaped in the remote shell by using escape character (`\`) in front of the spaces.

Comment: Just to emphasize - you need BOTH quotes and backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

look at rsync option –protect-args (-s), no extra slashes needed

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you would provide an example that the novice user could follow. Thank you!